# How can I exclude Facebook Messenger app usage from ScreenTime counting it as Facebook use on Mac?

Tags: macos, facebook, screen-time

I have set a time limit with ScreenTime for the usage of Facebook. My phone is properly counting time for the Facebook app and website together and it doesn't disable Messenger when I reach the limit.

However, I recently installed Messenger on my Mac and whenever I reach the limit for Facebook, MacOS disables Messenger app too.

How can I fix that so that Messenger isn't disabled? I need it as messaging is needed for me to communicate with people, I just want to limit my time scrolling on Facebook timeline?

Comment: Facebook time is facebook time. What do you expect?

Comment: I think you didn't get my point - iOS doesn't disable Messenger when the Facebook limit is reached, while MacOS does exactly that.

To me the function of Messenger isn't the same as the rest of the service, it has different value to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to find a solution for the same problem recently and have found a way.

What you have to do is first set the time limit for Facebook and then set Messenger App as "Always allowed". As I synchronise my Screen Time between my Mac and iPhone, it takes a short while before the change manifests on the second device. Also, when trying to find a way I noticed that my devices kind of confused the two apps (Messenger and Facebook) so you should better check after you are finished with the edits if Facebook is not in "Always allowed" instead of Messenger.

Hope this helps.